# IIS signs with the wrong Subject Alternative Name?

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-7

I am trying to configure our IIS to serve https over the following websites :
mywebsite
mywebsite.default.corporate.domain
servername/mywebsite

I set up 2 IIS websites hosted on this server.
One is the default and hosts various services, which means that some random bindings are activated (net.pipe, net.msmq, net.tcp), plus http and https.
The other one is mywebsite with 4 bindings : mywebsite and mywebsite.default.corporate.domain both over http and https.

I have generated a certificate in p12 format, with both mywebsite, mywebsite.default.corporate.domain and servername as subject alternative name, imported it in local computer personal certificates, and this is the certificate I am using for all 3 https binding.
I set the friendly name to *mywebsite and I edited the https bindings to match each expected domain.

Both mywebsite and servername/mywebsite work great, but mywebsite.default.corporate.domain shows an invalid certificate in chrome. When I check the details, the only subject alternative name is servername, even though the public key matches the one I get with the other two valid pages.

Following various questions and answers, I tried to set the IP adress in the bindings, tried the certutil -repairestore command and numerous IIS resets. I also tried to split the websites for mywebsite and mywebsite.default.corporate.domain.

If anyone has a suggestion, I am completely at loss here and spent way too much time on this already. I am using cutting edge technology (IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2).
Thanks !

Edit 1 : SSL Diagnostics Tool report as requested (anonymised as per company policy, sorry) :

```
System Time : Tuesday, June 02, 2020 2:20:52 PM Romance Standard Time
Processor Architecture : x64
OS : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5

SERVER SSL PROTOCOLS
PCT 1.0 : Enabled
SSL 2.0 : Enabled
SSL 3.0 : Enabled
TLS 1.0 : Enabled
SChannel EventLogging : 1 (hex)
-----
[W3SVC/1]
ServerComment   : Default Web Site
ServerAutoStart   : True
ServerState           : Started

BINDING : http *:80: 

BINDING : net.tcp 808:* 

BINDING : net.pipe * 

BINDING : net.msmq localhost 

BINDING : msmq.formatname localhost 


[W3SVC/2]
ServerComment   : mywebsite
ServerAutoStart   : True
ServerState           : Started

BINDING : http 184.11.52.120:80:mywebsite 

BINDING : https 184.11.52.120:443:mywebsite 
SSLCertHash : 8111C2E82C5AD2C3E556D5D523BE8C43C4AC46BB
SSL Flags : 
Testing EndPoint : 184.11.52.120:443 - Success
#CertName : *mywebsite
#Version : 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm : sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm : RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx Key Size : 2048
#Subject : CN=servername.default.corporate.domain, OU=STAR, O=MYCOMPANY, L=Paris, S=Ile de France, C=FR
#Issuer : CN=COMP UniPass Server Authentication 2016 CA, O=MYCOMPANY
#Validity : From Friday, May 29, 2020 6:04:08 PM To Tuesday, July 30, 2024 6:04:08 PM
#Serial Number : 4630C58DA21F1A05A8B348255FD0B168DDF104C3
DS Mapper Usage : Disabled
Archived : False
#Basic Constraints : Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None
#Authority Key Identifier : KeyID=fe 3b 7f 76 62 f8 80 36 04 95 8f 34 0a e1 6d af 72 31 6a df
#Authority Information Access : [1]Authority Info Access: Access Method=Certification Authority Issuer (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2), Alternative Name=URL=http://unipass.mycompany.com/ca/ServerAuthentication2016.crt
#Subject Alternative Name : DNS Name=servername.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=servername, DNS Name=staruat, DNS Name=staruat.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=mywebsite.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=mywebsite
#Enhanced Key Usage : Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)
#CRL Distribution Points : [1]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=ldap://ldap.unipass.mycompany/CN=ServerAuthentication2016,OU=UniPass,O=COMP?certificateRevocationList, [2]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=http://http.unipass.mycompany/?crlname=ServerAuthentication2016, [3]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=http://unipass.mycompany.com/crl/ServerAuthentication2016.crl
#Subject Key Identifier : 86 dd 98 41 1c db fc 08 af d1 e8 5b 04 a8 c0 ba 93 be 6f 2a
#Key Usage : Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Key Encipherment (e0)
Certificate verified.


[W3SVC/3]
ServerComment   : mywebsite.default.corporate.domain
ServerAutoStart   : True
ServerState           : Started

BINDING : https 184.11.52.120:443:mywebsite.default.corporate.domain 
SSLCertHash : 8111C2E82C5AD2C3E556D5D523BE8C43C4AC46BB
SSL Flags : 
Testing EndPoint : 184.11.52.120:443 - Success
#CertName : *mywebsite
#Version : 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm : sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm : RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx Key Size : 2048
#Subject : CN=servername.default.corporate.domain, OU=STAR, O=MYCOMPANY, L=Paris, S=Ile de France, C=FR
#Issuer : CN=COMP UniPass Server Authentication 2016 CA, O=MYCOMPANY
#Validity : From Friday, May 29, 2020 6:04:08 PM To Tuesday, July 30, 2024 6:04:08 PM
#Serial Number : 4630C58DA21F1A05A8B348255FD0B168DDF104C3
DS Mapper Usage : Disabled
Archived : False
#Basic Constraints : Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None
#Authority Key Identifier : KeyID=fe 3b 7f 76 62 f8 80 36 04 95 8f 34 0a e1 6d af 72 31 6a df
#Authority Information Access : [1]Authority Info Access: Access Method=Certification Authority Issuer (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2), Alternative Name=URL=http://unipass.mycompany.com/ca/ServerAuthentication2016.crt
#Subject Alternative Name : DNS Name=servername.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=servername, DNS Name=staruat, DNS Name=staruat.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=mywebsite.default.corporate.domain, DNS Name=mywebsite
#Enhanced Key Usage : Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)
#CRL Distribution Points : [1]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=ldap://ldap.unipass.mycompany/CN=ServerAuthentication2016,OU=UniPass,O=COMP?certificateRevocationList, [2]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=http://http.unipass.mycompany/?crlname=ServerAuthentication2016, [3]CRL Distribution Point: Distribution Point Name:Full Name:URL=http://unipass.mycompany.com/crl/ServerAuthentication2016.crl
#Subject Key Identifier : 86 dd 98 41 1c db fc 08 af d1 e8 5b 04 a8 c0 ba 93 be 6f 2a
#Key Usage : Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Key Encipherment (e0)
Certificate verified.

BINDING : http 184.11.52.120:80:mywebsite.default.corporate.domain 


-----
```

Edit 2 : Apparently the issue in intermitent which is even more incomprehensible/worrying to me.

Edit 3 : I have a feeling it is actually a client error. When the certificate is valid, the Certification Path is not the same as when the certificate is invalid. I am not sure this is possible but there seems to be 2 different corporate root certificate that chrome chooses from to validate my website certificate, one of which allows the good alias, and the other does not. I will contact the ssl support.

Edit 4 : Wanted to wait a bit to confirm that the issue disappeared for good, and it did. I do not have a good explanation but I think there was a configuration issue on our intranet maybe because my company does some weird man in the middle proxying and it might have been wrong for a while. I really do not have the level of expertise to understand what went wrong so this is yet another useless question on stackoverflow, my deepest sympathies if you end up on this question and expect some help...

Comment: Run some diagnostics and edit your question to include the report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: I have included the requested report. As far as I am concerned, the setup seems valid, but I must be missing something. I would prefer not to install this Jexus manager tool on our test server, but if you think this is absolutely necessary, I will look into it. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to fix this by enable server name indication?

Comment: I am under the impression that IIS 7.5 does not support SNI

Comment: Could you fix it by using different https port for these apps?